# Which conformer of beta D-glucose is more stable?

Tags: carbohydrates, conformers, stereoelectronics

I drew the two chair conformers of  $ \beta $-D-glucose:
[image]

Which one is more stable?

I think it's the one with all of the OH groups in the equatorial position because of less steric hindrance, but I also know that the anomeric effect makes the axial one favored as well.  So I'm unsure which is more stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also know that the anomeric effect makes the axial one favored as well.

The anomeric effect does stabilize an axial group, but *only* at the anomeric position. Other axial groups are not similarly stabilized. Thus $\alpha$-D-glucose is more stable than you think it should be based on steric considerations alone.

Knowing this, which is the more stable?

PS - very pretty chairs.

Comment: isn't the beta d-glucose the one with the equitorial bonds?

Comment: Both of your structures are beta-D-glucose, just different conformations. alpha-D-glucose is the anomer, and would have the OH at the anomeric position different. Otherwise, the two are the same.

Comment: right.  so i'm going to say the one on the left is more stable because the anomeric effic is still higher in energy than having all groups equitorial

Comment: And I would agree.